# How can I configure a Spring Security AuthenticationManager to be used with a JdbcUserDetailsManager?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

I have a web app that uses Spring Boot and Security configured to use form login with JDBC authentication.

Login and logout works fine and in general, auth seems to be working.

Except for one case... when I try to change my password, I notice that while the password change itself is successful, the AuthenticationManager that I want to verify the existing password... is null!

[image]

How can I configure an AuthenticationManager (perhaps with a DaoAuthenticationProvider and/or DaoAuthenticationManager?) so that the AuthenticationManager won't be null and will verify the existing password?

Relevant config:

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private RESTAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private RESTAuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    private RESTAuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler;

    @Autowired
    private RESTLogoutSuccessHandler restLogoutSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/h2-console/**")
                .permitAll();
        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/auth/**").authenticated();
        httpSecurity.cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource());
        httpSecurity.csrf()
                .ignoringAntMatchers("/h2-console/**")
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
        httpSecurity.headers()
                .frameOptions()
                .sameOrigin();
        httpSecurity.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);
        httpSecurity.formLogin().successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler);
        httpSecurity.formLogin().failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler);
        httpSecurity.logout().logoutSuccessHandler(restLogoutSuccessHandler);
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsManager configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        JdbcUserDetailsManagerConfigurer jdbcUserDetailsManagerConfigurer = auth.jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .withDefaultSchema();

        jdbcUserDetailsManagerConfigurer.withUser("user1")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("user1"))
                .roles("USER");

        return jdbcUserDetailsManagerConfigurer.getUserDetailsService();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12); // Strength increased as per OWASP Password Storage Cheat Sheet
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("X-XSRF-TOKEN", "Content-Type"));
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(List.of("Content-Disposition"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/login", configuration);
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/logout", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

AuthController, and here I want a UserDetailsManager injected on purpose - to easily be able to change account password:

```
import org.adventure.inbound.ChangePasswordData;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.UserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.security.Principal;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class AuthController {
    private UserDetailsManager userDetailsManager;
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public AuthController(UserDetailsManager userDetailsManager, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.userDetailsManager = userDetailsManager;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")
    @PutMapping(path = "changePassword", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> changePassword(@RequestBody ChangePasswordData changePasswordData, Principal principal) {
        if (principal == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Only logged in users may change their password");
        } else {
            if (changePasswordData.getCurrentPassword() == null || changePasswordData.getNewPassword() == null) {
                return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Either of the supplied passwords was null");
            } else {
                String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(changePasswordData.getNewPassword());
                userDetailsManager.changePassword(
                        changePasswordData.getCurrentPassword(), encodedPassword);
                return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I try the configuration mentioned [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60965000/2765587) in an answer, I get:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in org.adventure.controllers.AuthController required a  
bean of type 'org.springframework.security.provisioning.UserDetailsManager' that  
could not be found.

The following candidates were found but could not be injected:
    - Bean method 'inMemoryUserDetailsManager' in  
    'UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnBean  
    (types: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager,  
    org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider,  
    org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService,  
    org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder  
    org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.introspection.OpaqueTokenIntrospector;  
    SearchStrategy: all) found beans of type  
    'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService' userDetailsServiceBean
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This config seems to work OK. When changing passwords, existing user is authenticated by a DaoAuthenticationProvider which has a reference to the JdbcUserDetailsManager that is used by the AuthController

[image]
[image]

```java
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private RESTAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private RESTAuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    private RESTAuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler;

    @Autowired
    private RESTLogoutSuccessHandler restLogoutSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/h2-console/**")
                .permitAll();
        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/auth/**").authenticated();
        httpSecurity.cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource());
        httpSecurity.csrf()
                .ignoringAntMatchers("/h2-console/**")
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
        httpSecurity.headers()
                .frameOptions()
                .sameOrigin();
        httpSecurity.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);
        httpSecurity.formLogin().successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler);
        httpSecurity.formLogin().failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler);
        httpSecurity.logout().logoutSuccessHandler(restLogoutSuccessHandler);
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean
    public JdbcUserDetailsManager configureGlobal(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager,
                                                  AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        JdbcUserDetailsManagerConfigurer jdbcUserDetailsManagerConfigurer = auth.jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
                .withDefaultSchema();

        jdbcUserDetailsManagerConfigurer.withUser("user1")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("user1"))
                .roles("USER");

        JdbcUserDetailsManager jdbcUserDetailsManager = jdbcUserDetailsManagerConfigurer.getUserDetailsService();
        jdbcUserDetailsManager.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);

        return jdbcUserDetailsManager;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12); // Strength increased as per OWASP Password Storage Cheat Sheet
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("X-XSRF-TOKEN", "Content-Type"));
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(List.of("Content-Disposition"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/login", configuration);
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/logout", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this is the case, but couldn't you just do something similar to this, instead of going through the authmanager: Directly working with the currently loggedin user(details).

```
   @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public void changeUserPassword(@AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetails userDetails // whatever your userdetails implementation is..
                                               String newPassword,
                                               String oldPassword) {

        if (userDetails == null) {
            // user not logged in
        }

        String currentEncryptedPassword = userDetails.getPassword();
        if (!currentEncryptedPassword.equals(passwordEncoder.encode(oldPassword))) {
            // wrong password
        }

        dao.updatepasswd(user, passwordencoder.encode(newsPassword)) //change password in db..
    }
```

Comment: This won't work as the injection isn't happening inside a Spring Security class.

Answer (score 0):

Your setup is flawed, as you enable too early instantiation of the `UserDetailsService` what you should be doing

1. Your `configureGlobal` method should return `void`.
2. Override the `userDetailsServiceBean`, call `super` and annotate that with `@Bean`. As documented [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.html#userDetailsServiceBean--)
3. You should be setting the `passwordEncoder` on your `userDetailsService` configuration and don't encode the password yourself when creating the user.
4. You should have `@EnableWebSecurity` on your class as well.

That way Spring Security will properly initialize and configure all the components. (Although 3 and 4 aren't related, they should be set for proper configuration in the general sense).

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private RESTAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private RESTAuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    private RESTAuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler;

    @Autowired
    private RESTLogoutSuccessHandler restLogoutSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/h2-console/**")
                .permitAll();
        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/auth/**").authenticated();
        httpSecurity.cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource());
        httpSecurity.csrf()
                .ignoringAntMatchers("/h2-console/**")
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
        httpSecurity.headers()
                .frameOptions()
                .sameOrigin();
        httpSecurity.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);
        httpSecurity.formLogin().successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler);
        httpSecurity.formLogin().failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler);
        httpSecurity.logout().logoutSuccessHandler(restLogoutSuccessHandler);
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        JdbcUserDetailsManagerConfigurer jdbcUserDetailsManagerConfigurer = auth.jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
                .withDefaultSchema();

        jdbcUserDetailsManagerConfigurer.withUser("user1")
                .password("user1")
                .roles("USER");

    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceBean() {
        super.userDetailsServiceBean();
    }

}
```

Comment: I added some more info to the question.

Comment: i don't think this is what the  owner of the question wants, it did not provide an instance of the UserDetailsManager...

Comment: It used to expose one, however apparently in a recent version that has changed (there is now some lazy wrapper around it). Which only exposes the `userDetailsService`.